# Add a second trigger to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I currently have this...

```
var phpArray = <?php echo json_encode($tourdistance['tourdistance']); ?>;
$('#tour').on('change', function (event) {
$('#distance').val(phpArray[$(this).val()]);
});
```

...updating an input element 'distance' when a drop down 'tour' is changed. When the form is submitted, with validation errors, I have the HTML/PHP set up so that it remembers the users choice for that field. However, the above is not triggered unless they re-select that drop down element. Which is a poor user experience because visually it will look correctly selected.

How can I also have it update on page-load, or otherwise setup so that 'distance' stays updated, even after a page load?

Here is the page...

http://antipodecycling.com/donate-support/sponsor-us/

Current solution:

```
var phpArray = <?php echo json_encode($tourdistance['tourdistance']); ?>;

$(document).ready(function(){
   function updateSelect(){
       var selectInput = $("#tour");
       var distance = phpArray[selectInput.val()];
       $('#distance').val(distance);
    }
    updateSelect();

    function updatePledge(){
       var pledge = "<?php echo set_value('pledge'); ?>";
       $('#pledge').val(pledge);
    }
    updatePledge();


   $("#tour").on('change', function(){
        updateSelect();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abstract the update function, and then call on two different events: document ready and select change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   function updateSelect(){

       alert('update select fired');

       var selectInput = $("#tour");

       var distance = phpArray[selectInput.val()];
       alert(distance);

       $('#distance').val(distance);
       $('#pledgedistance').html(distance);
    }

   updateSelect();

   $("#tour").on('change', function(){
        updateSelect();
   });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to break both actions.

Comment: You seem to have dropped the tourdistance array reference

Comment: hmm..if you posted your HTML might help

Comment: OK I updated the question with the link. Selecting a tour will create a distance. Submitting the form will generate validation errors. What I want after that is for the user to not have to select a tour again.

Comment: looks like you need to update your hidden input AND your display `<span>` so I added that. also added some alerts, that should help debug and show you what's getting called and when, and what the values are.

Comment: OK I'll try, FYI the span is being updated by a later js, based on the hidden input. Result is that 'Estimated Distance' is not updated at all now even when directly selecting the tour.

Comment: Wait it seems to work... I just added the array php back at the top

Comment: Hmmm it would be amazing if 'Pledge' updated on page load in the same way. The validation scripts carry over the value, but it's lost from the Estimated Total calc. i.e. you have to re-enter the value. PS thanks so much for this.

Comment: i assumed you were going to do that as well, and just asking this for reference, since it should basically be the same thing.

Comment: Cool I'm trying now, basically I add another function and call that yeah?

Comment: OK I added my attempt in the OP. The extra function does indeed update the element, but it doesn't drive the 'Estimated Total' to change unless you change a value after page load. Am I close? FYI 'Total' is recalculated on input change normally when filling the form.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I also have it update on page-load

Just [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event on page load:

```
var phpArray = <?php echo json_encode($tourdistance['tourdistance']); ?>;
$('#tour').on('change', function() {
   $('#distance').val(phpArray[$(this).val()]);
}).change();
```

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter form validation. Do you know if it's a full page load for an invalid field/form? It looks like it, but the code above doesn't fire. 'Distance' is not set.

Comment: i.e. it works as before, with a drop down change, but not after hitting the form submit button and loading the validation errors.

Comment: I don't know about CodeIgniter, sorry. Don't its docs say how it works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's reloading. How does your code work? I'm assuming it listens for a change in 'tour' and runs, but also runs on page load. Is there anywhere in particular this script should be in relation to page content, and other js on the page?

Comment: Codeigniter sets the HTML as `<option selected>`. I'm no JS guru, but my guess would be this doesn't fire a `change` event, since the selected option is just set on page load.

Comment: It should just be in the place where it was before. It installs the listener, and instantly fires an event to execute it for initialisation. If codeigniter reloads the page, it should be executed again; if codeigniter changes the value without it should fire a `change` event (or at least provide a callback). If codeigniter does some initialisation where it changes the value, my code should go after that.